# How to add a row to a sparse matrix in itpp

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

In matlab we write :

```
H2= H(p==1,:)
```

where H2 and H are sparse double matrix and p is a logical vector.

how I can write it in [itpp](http://itpp.sourceforge.net/4.3.1/)?

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% familiar with itpp, but I would try something like

```
int h = 0, w = H.cols();
// count number of set elements in p to get number of rows of H2
for ( int i = 0 ; i < p.length() ; i++ ) {
    h += (p[i] == 1);
}
// alocate H2
H2 = Sparse_Mat( h, w, H.nnz() ); // estimate number of nonzeros in H2
// copy the relevant elements
for ( int i = 0, i2 = 0 ; i < p.length() && i2 < h  ; i++ ) {
    if ( p[i] != 1 ) {
       continue;
    }
    H2.set_submatrix( i2, 0, H.get_submatrix( i, i+1, 0, w ).full() );
    i2++;
}
```

Clearly, working with sparse columns is much easier using `get_col` and `set_col`, so you might consider transposing `H` first and then perform the operation returning `H2.transpose()`.

Comment: thanks, Does transposing the matrix take more computation time? how much it will be worse?. I think that getting full() of matrix is not a good idea because it takes more computation and space.

Comment: @abdolahS transposing is costy as well as `full`, you can try and do it element by element for the relevant rows. Performance depends on the data and you'll have to try it yourself.